# Singular matrix for solving Helmholtz PDE with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

I am trying to solve the Helmholtz PDE $-\nabla^2u + u = f \quad \text{on} \; \Omega$ with homogeneous Neumann boundary condition $\partial_n u = 0 \; \text{on} \; \partial \Omega$.

I noted that an unique solution does exist given the PDE contains the "u" term as itself. I proceeded to discretize the domain using linear quad elements and further use Galerkin method to arrive at the stiffness expression $[A]\{u\} = \{F\}$, where   the elemental stiffness matrix was $[A_e]_{ij} = \int \limits_{\Omega_e} (\phi_i\phi_j + \nabla \phi_i \nabla \phi_j) d\Omega_e$.

However, I find that the matrix are singular and I am unable to decipher why they are so. Given that the BC is homogeneous Neumann everywhere, I suppose no special consideration be given to include them ( Am I wrong to assume so ? ).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible that $-1$ is a homogeneous Neumann eigenvalue of the Laplacian on your domain, i.e. that a solution to the homogeneous version of your PDE with homegeneous Neumann boundary conditions exists? Note that this could potentially be the case for the discretization and not for the underlying problem.

Comment: Your matrix $A_e$ is not consistent with the PDE on the first line. The matrix $A_e$, you wrote, is for the equation $-\Delta u + u = f$.

Comment: @user7440 thanks for pointing out the error. I think it is a typo in my question ( I missed the negative sign) . The matrix is still singular. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the matrix you get on a nice simple domain like a square? It seems likely to me that the kernel of your matrix has some simple (nonzero) elements (similar to how constants are in the kernel of the homogeneous Neumann Laplacian).

Comment: Assuming that your mesh is conforming and that you are integrating exactly, then the matrix $A$ should be invertible. It is the discrete version of the $H^1$ inner product. I think what you see suggests a bug.